# Is there any solution for $u^x+v^y=v^z$ with $x,y,z\ge 2$ and $v>u$

Tags: number-theory

> Is there any solution for $a,b,x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that
>
> $$a^x+(a+b)^y=(a+b)^z$$
>
> Where $x,y,z\ge 2$.

checked between $[2\le x,y,z \le 10]$,$[1\le a,b\le 500]$

```
for(x=2,10,for(y=2,10,for(z=2,10,for(a=1,500,for(b=1,500,if(sum(q=1,1,a^x)+(sum(w=1,1,(a+b)^y))==(a+b)^z,print([a,x,a+b,y,a+b,z])))))))
```

But there are solutions for

$$\begin{split}a^x+(a+b)^y&=(a+2b)^z\\1^2+2^3 &=3^2\\3^2+4^2 &=5^2\\5^3+10^2 &=15^2\end{split}$$

And

$$\begin{split}a^x+(a+b)^y&=(a+3b)^z\\ 
 4^3+6^2&=10^2\\2^4+3^2&=5^2\end{split}$$

And

$$\begin{split}a^x+(a+b)^y&=(a+4b)^z\\3^2+6^3&=15^2\\ 
 21^3+42^2&=105^2\end{split}$$

And maybe there always exist solution for all $k>1$ s.t. $a^x+(a+b)^y=(a+kb)^z$ but not for $k=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the equation you're asking about, there's no solutions for $k = 1$. To see this, first note you have $z \gt y$. Also, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a^x + (a+b)^y & = (a+b)^z \\
a^x & = (a+b)^z - (a+b)^y \\
a^x & = (a+b)^y((a+b)^{z-y} - 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $\gcd((a + b)^y, (a + b)^{z - y} - 1) = 1$, there are positive integers $c$ and $d$ such that $a = cd$ as well as

$$c^x = (a+b)^y \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$d^x = (a+b)^{z-y} - 1 \implies (a+b)^{z-y} - d^x = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

However, [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), also known as Mihăilescu's theorem since it was proven in $2002$ by Preda Mihăilescu, states the only solution in the natural numbers of

$$x^a - y^b = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

for $a, b \gt 1$, plus $x, y \gt 0$, is $x = 3$, $a = 2$, $y = 2$, $b = 3$. Since in \eqref{eq3A} you have $x \gt 1$, if $z - y \gt 1$ as well, then you must have

$$a + b = 3 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$z - y = 2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

$$x = 3 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

$$d = 2 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

This gives in \eqref{eq1A} that

$$a^3 = (3^y)(8) \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

However, since \eqref{eq5A} gives $a = 1$ or $a = 2$, this isn't possible. Thus, this means that

$$z - y = 1 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

As such, \eqref{eq3A} becomes

$$d^x = a + b - 1 \implies a + b = d^x + 1 \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Substituting this into \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$c^x = (d^x + 1)^y \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

You have

$$(d^x + 1)^y \gt (d^x)^y = (d^y)^x \implies c \gt d^y \tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

However, you have from \eqref{eq1A} that $x \gt y$, which gives that

$$(d^y + 1)^x \gt (d^x + 1)^y \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

To see this, recall that $\ln(x)$ is a strictly monotonically increasing function for positive $x$, so take $\ln$ of both sides and consider

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(x,y) & = x\ln(d^y + 1) - y\ln(d^x + 1) \\
& = x\left(\ln(d^y) + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^y}\right)\right) - y\left(\ln(d^x) + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^x}\right)\right) \\
& = xy\ln(d) + x\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^y}\right) - xy\ln(d) - y\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^x}\right) \\
& = x\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^y}\right) - y\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^x}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{15}\label{eq15A}$$

Note $f(x,y) = 0$. Next, take the partial derivative wrt $x$ of $f$ in \eqref{eq14A} to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} & = \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^y}\right) - y\left(\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{d^x}}\right)(-x)\left(\frac{1}{d^{x+1}}\right) \\
& = \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{d^y}\right) + xy\left(\frac{1}{d^{x+1} + d}\right) \\
& \gt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{16}\label{eq16A}$$

This shows $f(x,y) \gt 0$ for $x \gt y$, which shows that \eqref{eq14A} is true. However, from \eqref{eq12A}, this shows that $(d^y + 1)^x \gt c^x \implies d^y + 1 \gt c$. Along with \eqref{eq13A}, you get

$$d^y + 1 \gt c \gt d^y \tag{17}\label{eq17A}$$

This shows there's no integral solution for $c$ in \eqref{eq12A}, confirming that there's no solution for the case of $k = 1$, i.e., as shown in \eqref{eq1A}.

As for there always existing at least one solution for each $k \gt 1$, I don't know whether or not it's true, although I suspect it is. I see you've confirmed it is true for at least $k = 2, 3$ and $4$.

Comment: Thanks, very clever proof and elementary too. I think given solution  some progress on Beal conjecture.

Comment: Please Check Related posts https://mathoverflow.net/q/354452/149083

Comment: @Pruthviraj You're welcome, & thanks for the compliment. What I've shown is just a quite small part related to the Beal conjecture. There are various specific parts which can be proven, but be careful to not generalize too much, as you've seen in your MO related post. I believe, similar to the related Fermat's last theorem where many specific cases were proven but it took a new method to prove the general case, a similar situation will likely occur with Beal's conjecture. Nonetheless, it's still useful & interesting to prove specific cases, and some might even help lead to a general solution.

Comment: @Pruthviraj Note I spent some time checking if I could find Pythagorean triples for each value of $k \gt 1$, but I didn't see anything offhand I could use. Nonetheless, I believe there is likely a way to show this using just squares if I spent more time checking on it. Alternatively, having $1$, or even $2$, cubes could also be used in some cases.